# Un-escape HTML string in Windows 8 metro application

Tags: c#, windows-8, html-parsing

How can I un-escape HTML string in Windows 8 metro application.

for regular C# application I can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, but that class is not available in the Metro/Windows RT framework.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, you can add your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`